# Insert multiple values from select

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I have mysql query for inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_hash, address_sender_id, address_receiver_id)
SELECT ? AS transaction_hash,
       id AS address_sender_id,
       tmp.address_receiver_id
FROM addresses
JOIN
  (SELECT id AS address_receiver_id
   FROM addresses
   WHERE address = ?) AS tmp
WHERE address = ?.
```

For single data like `[hash, address1, address2]` its works perfect. How can I refactor this query for inserting multiple values: `[[hash_1, hash_2], [address1_1, address1_2], [address2_1, address2_2]]`
[image: Finally data] 
I give hash as static string. And two different address ids (string too) of which takes from another table

Comment: Are you talking json here or storing csv values. It would help if you could show how your stored data would look.

Comment: Where is the `ON` clause saying how the two `SELECTs` relate?